# What directory do I have to put my input file for a C program?

Tags: c, input, io

I'm using Netbeans to write a C program. Where do I need to paste my input.txt file for the program to read it if I don't want to specify a directory in the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) where the program executes.  You'll have to see where exactly Netbeans causes the binary to be output, but most likely, you will want your input.txt file to be in that same directory. Possibly a `bin` subdirectory of wherever your source is.

Comment: Note that it depends where it "runs" the executable rather than where the executable is. If, for example, the executable (`a.out`) is inside `your/project/dir/bin` folder, and it calls it from `your/project/dir` like this: `bin/a.out`, then input.txt needs to be in `your/project/dir`

Comment: Right - some IDEs are screwy about that, but I was taking a stab that Netbeans will execute it from the directory it is in.

Comment: Just put the note so that if it was actually the case, the OP wouldn't give you a -1 ;)